# Meteor Semantic-UI-React: focusing components

Tags: reactjs, meteor, reactive-programming, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am building an app with Meteor, React and Semantic-UI. I am new in these frameworks/libraries.
After reading the docs, I still don't understand how to set the focus on a component, because some say you can't do it yet, others say that you can but their example doesn't work for me.
In the below example the `options` are defined as constants and imported from another document, and the `changeHospital` & `changeActivity` functions just set the state of the `hospital` and `activity` with the `data.value` from the options:

```
          <Form.Field
            label='Hospital'
            control={Select}
            fluid
            search
            value={this.state.hospital}
            placeholder='Select hospital'
            options={hospitals}
            onChange={this.changeHospital}
          />

          <Form.Field
            label='Activity'
            control={Select}
            search
            fluid
            value={this.state.app}
            placeholder='Select activity'
            options={apps}
            onChange={this.changeActivity}
          />
```

**What do I want?**

After submitting the first field I want to change the focus on the next field automatically without pressing the tab key or selecting it with the mouse cursor.

**Later edit**

If you can understand more than me you can read the docs for the semantic-ui-react component at: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.js

They say:

```
/** A dropdown can receive focus. */
tabIndex: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.number,
  PropTypes.string,
]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know semantic-ui-react, but I do know react, so this is a guess based on how you would solve it with a normal react input.

```
// Add ref to the field you want to focus
<Form.Field
    ref="activityField"
    label="Activity"
    control={Select}
    search
    fluid
    value={this.state.app}
    placeholder="Select activity"
    options={apps}
    onChange={this.changeActivity}
/>

// Update function from previous input
changeHospital() {
    ... // do what you already do, then change focus
    this.refs.activityField.focus()
}
```

Calling `.focus()` on a react input focuses it, but it's possible that `Form.Field` does not handle `.focus()` and in that case it won't work.

Comment: Sorry for voting your answer. It would have been helpful if semantic-ui wouldn't have overriden this property. If you can understand more than me you can read the docs for the dropdown control https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.js
They say:
/** A dropdown can receive focus. */
    tabIndex: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.number,
      PropTypes.string,
    ]),